# Issue setting max line length for PEP8 in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, pep8

I am using `Eclipse Juno` on an `Ubuntu x64` machine.

I would like to change the default max line length for the `PyDev`'s PEP8, but I can't!

I go to Window/Preferences/PyDev/Editor/Code Analysis/pep8.py and set the following arguments:

```
--max-line-length=100
```

What I am doing wrong? After setting this, I have done a code analysis but then the line length seems to be ignored and I don't want this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To set the maximum line length, go to:

```
Window/Preferences/PyDev/Editor/Code Analysis/pep8.py
```

Then, open the file at `Location of pep8.py`, search for `MAX_LINE_LENGTH` variable and set it to the length you want. You just have to restart Eclipse and that's it! :D

*Note: make sure PyDev's options `Do code analysis?` is checked.*

Comment: @Caumons I am sorry but I am not able to find location of pep8.py on my eclipse kepler with PyDev. Can you please help?

Comment: @Naman: For me (eclipse 4.4, linux) pep8.py is to be found here: ~/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.0_77104185_linux_gtk_x86_64/plugins/org.python.pydev_3.6.0.201406232321/pysrc/third_party/pep8/pep8.py

Comment: @A-B-B at the time I wrote this answer this was the way to go, 3 years and a half later, things may have changed... Actually, there are other newer answers that already show how to do it in later versions.

Answer (score 16):

The current Pydev has a pep8.py that can set the `--max-line-length` parameter. You can just go to

```
Window → Preferences → Pydev → Editor → Code Analysis → pep8.py
```

and set Arguments to:

```
--max-line-length=99
```

Comment: Argument is managed since PyDev 3.6.0 (I successfully tested it with version 3.9.0):  https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/2a7c8324ebd79fa7c84ebd150b4383cef2569726

Comment: To save other people pain, I discovered that you need to restart Eclipse for changes to the arguments setting to take effect.

Comment: ... and I just rediscovered my own comment. I badly need to change to PyCharm! :-D

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the maximum line length is not implemented in the pep8.py used by pydev. This means that it will not recognize the maximum line length.

If you use '- max-line-length "as you can see in the logs that it is subject to one exception and that is when it is about to parse arguments. If you open the file that the error comes from, one can see that "- max-line-length" is missing.

The log can be obtained through Help-> Aptana-> View Log File.
Check for error in "pep8.py"

To make this work you probably have to ask that they fix this upstream or fix it yourself locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I can't see the log file as I don't have the option "Aptana" in Help menu :S It's a pitty that this feature isn't available.

Comment: Ok, I forgott that you were using Eclipse and not Aptana. The logfile should then be located in <workspace>/.metadata/.log

Comment: +1 Took me some time to realize that too. This answer could have saved me a lot of that time.

Comment: @pwagner & Henke I've just included another answer that actually does solve the problem. Cheers!

Comment: The current pydev version has a pep8.py that has the --max-line-length parameter!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like PyDev's support for PEP8 has improved since this question was asked. I got it to work by going to Window: Preferences: PyDev: Editor: Code Analysis, and then clicking on the pep8.py tab.

I entered the argument `--max-line-length=100`, but it was ignored as you describe. However, when I enabled the "Use system interpreter" checkbox, the arguments were used. I also found that the `--ignore` setting works.

I am using PyDev 4.2.0 with Eclipse 4.4.2 (Luna).